# Load image from URL in C++

Tags: c++, image, http, opencv, poco-libraries

I am using C++ and OpenCV and I'd like to load an image from password protected URL.
I succeeded in loading image from URL using idea of this [link](http://techify.giridharsweb.com/2012/08/05/read-image-from-url-into-opencv/) which uses POCO library, but I do not know what should I do when I have to use username and password in order to access the URL.

Comment: Is it HTTP authentication, or is it a web login where you have to fill out a form and use cookies with?

Comment: @StevenV It is HTTP authentication.

Comment: If the library follows RFC 3986, the obvious thing to try is `http://username:password@example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say do what @StevenV said and try to encode the credentials in the URI.

If that doesn't work or you don't want to use that method you have to use the POCO HTTPClientSession class instead. Something like this:

```
URI uri(url);
HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
HTTPRequest req(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, uri.getPathEtc(), HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
HTTPBasicCredentials creds("username","password");
creds.authenticate(req);
session.sendRequest(req);
HttpResponse resp;
std::istream file = session.reveiveResponse(resp);
if(resp.getStatus() == HTTP_OK){
  //copy image from istream file here;
}
```