# How to check if the server is available in POCO::Net

Tags: c++, http, client-server, poco, poco-libraries

I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383270/load-image-from-url-in-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to load the frames of Ip Camera. When the camera is not connected, I get exception. Is there a way to check if the camera is connected? In the other hand, can I check if my client can connect to server in the poco?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in try/catch. If you get exception, something went wrong.

```
try
{
//this will throw Poco::Net::ConectionRefusedException
session.sendRequest(req);
//...
}
catch(Poco::Net::ConectionRefusedException& ex)
{
// handle error
}
```